# Laravel storing many gigabytes of cache storage files and does not automatically erase old cache

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.8.12

I am noticing that laravel `/storage` is saving over 10gb of cache storage. And doesn't seem to clear up.

But why is it constantly building cached files? Isn't there suppose to be a garbage collector or automated cache clear/replace.

**This does not seem sustainable.**

To confirm, all of this data is being stored in `/storage/framework/cache`

I have not changed the default settings in the cache config.

Yes, I know I can create my own cache clear script, but the point is, why is it doing this and how do I prevent it from happening. It will take the remaining disk space on the server...

Comment: I would suggest setting up a cron to run `php artisan cache:clear` periodically.

Comment: Are you sure it's your cache folder that is 10gb? Not your log folder?

Comment: @Jeemusu, yes `10.2G ./cache`

Comment: Honestly, this seems like a Laravel bug, there is no reason the cache should ever do this on vanilla settings.

Comment: @Jeemusu I do have a lot of traffic that hits this web api. So its not building on its own, but I dont even ask laravel to cache anything, this is default laravel caching.

Comment: If your not asking Laravel to cache anything there shouldn't be anything in the framework/cache folder. Laravel doesn't cache anything by default. What is the contents of the files? That should give you a clue as to what is being cached. It could be package caching something.

Comment: @Jeemusu, so far its random files like `43/e8` and the contents of random numbers like `1555436884i:1555436884;`, millions of files it looks like.

Comment: Those look related to timers.Sounds like it could be a bug. If your not using throttling, removing it from the API middlewear should solve it.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15152

Comment: @Jeemusu I checked I'm using `Laravel Framework 5.8.12`.

Comment: Should be solved in 5.8.12 .. although the cache data does seem to be time stamps.. are you using throttling on the API?

Comment: If you cache things just once and the cache is not hit at least a second time, it will not clean up expired items. Such items are only cleaned when they are looked up in the cache but they are already expired. See [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php#L180-L187).

Comment: I get same cache content if I cache a timestamp: `Cache::put('test', now()->timestamp, now()->addMinutes(4))` gives `1558427915i:1558427675;` Maybe try to debug the `put` method to trace the source?

Answer (score 4):

Periodically cleaning cache needs some further efforts. You need to set up a cron job with `systemd` or whatever cron job runner you're comfortable with.
Then run `php artisan cache:clear` in the job.
[reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling)

Comment: OP clearly says: `Yes, I know I can create my own cache clear script, but the point is, why is it doing this`.

Comment: Because the cache is just aggregated over time and never gets a chance to be cleared.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I realized its mainly due to throttling requests. Laravel is not good with file driver cache when dealing with millions of requests. So it will need to be manually cleared at this point. unless I use something like Redis, which can automatically clear the older cache.

Comment: Yeah, besides some hard times having with file cache, Redis is a much faster utility for cache storing since it's using memory instead of a hard drive. Besides, you will get a better experience in clustering, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Some cache storages, such as `memcached` or `redis`, implements TTL feature on their own, so you don't have to clear timed out cache. So I think, due to [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) and [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), cache driver shouldn't be in charge of clearing old cache.

But I sure it MUST be at least mentioned in cache docs and I don't have answer to question "why it isn't".